# Setting alignment of different groups of JComponent objects

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, alignment

I have a question regarding how to align my components on my GUI.

[image: Screen capture of GUI]

Referring to the screen capture above, I want the checkboxes to be aligned with each other, but here I'm getting that one checkbox (LC Proxy) which is out of line, due to there being an additional combo box on the same line.

Can anyone suggest the necessary changes I should make to achieve what I want? (Other suggestions on how to improve the code/display are also welcome!)

(P/S Sorry if the title is misleading; not sure how else I can name it)

Here's the code for my GUI:

```
/**
 * Builds the elements for the GUI
 */
private void build() {
    // define properties
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocation(100, 100);
    this.setSize(360, 250);
    this.setResizable(false);

    // build elements
    movFileField = new JTextField(30);
    movFileField.setEditable(false);
    JLabel textFieldLabel = new JLabel("MOV file: ");
    textFieldLabel.setLabelFor(movFileField);

    JPanel filenamePane = new JPanel();
    filenamePane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    filenamePane.add(textFieldLabel);
    filenamePane.add(movFileField);

    JCheckBox checkIPV = new JCheckBox("IPV Proxy");
    checkIPV.setSelected(configMap.get(EpoxyConfigField.IPV_PROXY.name()).isEnabled());
    toggleMap.put(EpoxyConfigField.IPV_PROXY, checkIPV);
    flickComps.add(checkIPV);

    JCheckBox checkITX = new JCheckBox("ITX Proxy");
    checkITX.setSelected(configMap.get(EpoxyConfigField.ITX_PROXY.name()).isEnabled());
    toggleMap.put(EpoxyConfigField.ITX_PROXY, checkITX);
    flickComps.add(checkITX);

    JCheckBox checkLC = new JCheckBox("LC Proxy");
    checkLC.setSelected(configMap.get(EpoxyConfigField.LC_PROXY.name()).isEnabled());
    toggleMap.put(EpoxyConfigField.LC_PROXY, checkLC);
    flickComps.add(checkLC);

    JComboBox<String> comboLCProfile = new JComboBox<String>("A;C;D;Dxd;E".split(";"));

    JCheckBox checkArchive = new JCheckBox("Archive Asset");
    checkArchive.setSelected(configMap.get(EpoxyConfigField.ARCHIVE.name()).isEnabled());
    toggleMap.put(EpoxyConfigField.ARCHIVE, checkArchive);
    flickComps.add(checkArchive);

    JPanel checkboxPane = new JPanel();
    checkboxPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(checkboxPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    checkboxPane.add(checkIPV);
    checkboxPane.add(checkITX);

// This is the part I'm having problems with
    JPanel lcproxyPane = new JPanel();
    lcproxyPane.add(checkLC);
    lcproxyPane.add(comboLCProfile);
    checkboxPane.add(lcproxyPane);

    checkboxPane.add(checkArchive);
    checkboxPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

    JButton processButton = new JButton("Process");
    processButton.setActionCommand(COMMAND_PROCESS);
    processButton.addActionListener(this);
    flickComps.add(processButton);

    JButton selectButton = new JButton("Select");
    selectButton.setActionCommand(COMMAND_SELECT);
    selectButton.addActionListener(this);
    flickComps.add(selectButton);

    statusField = new JTextArea(10,20);
    statusField.setEditable(false);
    statusField.setLineWrap(true);

    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
    buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(50, 0)));
    buttonPane.add(processButton);
    buttonPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    buttonPane.add(selectButton);
    buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(50, 0)));
    buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,10,10,10));

    JPanel bottomPane = new JPanel();
    bottomPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    bottomPane.add(buttonPane);
    bottomPane.add(new JScrollPane(statusField));

    Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(filenamePane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    contentPane.add(checkboxPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(bottomPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    this.pack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot align your components is because you used a layout which makes very difficult to align those components.
I suggest you to use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) rather than FlowLayout.

Example:

```
    JPanel checkboxPane = new JPanel();

    GridBagLayout gbl_checkboxPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_checkboxPane.columnWidths = new int[]{430, 0, 0};
    gbl_checkboxPane.rowHeights = new int[]{27, 27, 27, 27};
    gbl_checkboxPane.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_checkboxPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    checkboxPane.setLayout(gbl_checkboxPane);

    JCheckBox checkIPV = new JCheckBox("IPV Proxy");

    GridBagConstraints gbc_checkIPV = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_checkIPV.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_checkIPV.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc_checkIPV.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_checkIPV.gridx = 0;
    gbc_checkIPV.gridy = 0;
    checkboxPane.add(checkIPV, gbc_checkIPV);
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. The thing is I have been experimenting with different layouts but I haven't been getting much results, due to my lack of knowledge in the different managers. I will give this a try and see what happens!

Comment: Using Swing layouts it is not an easy task. What I really suggest you to do is to install eclipse with a plugin called Windows Builder. Using this tool you can see what you are building in real time. Good luck